# Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets

Tags: cakephp, string, file-upload

Depois de fazer o upload do meu site, o formulário para inserir imagens deixou de funcionar, ao clicar no botão para guardar obtenho :

> Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in `...`app/Plugin/Uploader/Model/Behavior/FileValidationBehavior.php on line 283

Independente de selecionar imagem quer não. Qual é a solução para este problema?

Estou a utilizar a versão 2.4.4 do cake.

**Model**

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class GalleryImage extends AppModel{

    public $displayField ='path';
    public $useTable = 'gallery_images';

    //public $actsAs = array('MultipleDisplayFields' => array('fields' => array('path', 'id')));

    var $name = 'GalleryImage';

    var $validate= array(
        'path' => array(
            'is_valid' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty'/*'fileSelected'*/,
                'message' => 'Seleccione uma fotografia por favor.'//,
                //'allowEmpty' => false//,
                //'last' => true,
                //'required'=> true
                ),

            //'extension' => array(
            //  'rule' => array('extension', array('gif','jpeg','png','jpg')),
            //  'message'=> 'A imagem deve estar num formato gif, jpeg, png ou jpg.',
                //'last' => true,
                //'required'=> true
            //  ),
            'is_unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Uma fotografia com este nome já existe.'
                //'required'=> true
                )
            //),
        //'size' => array(
                //'rule' => array(/*'checkSize',true*/'fileSize','<=','2MB'),
                //'on' => 'create',
                //'message' => 'O ficheiro deve ter um tamanho igual ou inferior a 2MB.'

                //'last' => true,
                //'required'=> true
                )
        );
public $actsAs = array(
    'Uploader.FileValidation' => array(
        'file' => array(
            'extension' => array('gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'),
            'type' => 'image',

            'filesize' => 2097152,
            'allowEmpty' => array(
                'value' => false,
                'error' => 'Seleccione uma fotografia por favor.'
                )
        )
    ),
    'Uploader.Attachment' => array(
        'file' => array(
                'finalPath' => '',
                'uploadDir' => 'img/gallery/',
                'dbColumn' => 'path'
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function admin_upload_image(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Inserir Fotografias');
        if(!$this->Session->check('User')) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Está a aceder a uma zona restrita. Por favor faça Login.');
            $this->redirect(array(
                            'controller' => 'users',
                            'action' => 'login'));
        }

        $this->layout = 'admin_index';
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
          /*  $file = $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name'];*/

        $file = array(
            'GalleryImage' => array(
                'path' => $this->request->data['GalleryImage']['file']['name']//,
                //'size' => $this->request->data['GalleryImage']['file']['size']
                   )
                );
            $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');

            $this->GalleryImage->create();

            if(/*$this->GalleryImage->save($file)*/$this->GalleryImage->save($this->request->data,true)){

               /*move_uploaded_file($this->data['GalleryImage']['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html/PushUp/app/webroot/img/gallery/' . $this->data['GalleryImage']['file']['name']);
                */
                //$validationErrors = $this->GalleryImage->invalidFields();
                //$this->Session->setFlash($validationErrors['path']); // named key of the rule
                $this->Session->setFlash('Fotografia guardada com sucesso.', 'default', array('class'=>'alert alert-success'));
            }
            else{
                //$validationErrors = $this->GalleryImage->invalidFields();
               //$this->Session->setFlash($validationErrors['file']); // named key of the rule
               $this->Session->setFlash('Erro ao carregar o ficheiro!', 'default', array('class'=>'alert alert-danger'));
                //return false;

                //$error = $this->Notification->validationErrors;
                //$this->set('error', $error);

                //$this->Session->setFlash(__($error), 'Flash/warning');
            }
        }
    }
```

**FileValidationBehavior.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * FileValidationBehavior
 *
 * A CakePHP Behavior that adds validation model rules to file uploading.
 *
 * @author      Miles Johnson - http://milesj.me
 * @copyright   Copyright 2006-2011, Miles Johnson, Inc.
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php - Licensed under The MIT   License
 * @link        http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader
 */

App::uses('ModelBehavior', 'Model');

App::import('Vendor', 'Uploader.Uploader');

class FileValidationBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

/**
 * Current settings.
 *
 * @access protected
 * @var array
 */
protected $_settings = array();

/**
 * Default list of validation sets.
 *
 * @access protected
 * @var array
 */

protected $_defaults = array(
    'width' => array(
        'rule' => array('width'),
        'message' => 'Your image width is invalid; required width is %s.'
    ),
    'height' => array(
        'rule' => array('height'),
        'message' => 'Your image height is invalid; required height is %s.'
    ),
    'minWidth' => array(
        'rule' => array('minWidth'),
        'message' => 'Your image width is too small; minimum width %s.'
    ),
    'minHeight' => array(
        'rule' => array('minHeight'),
        'message' => 'Your image height is too small; minimum height %s.'
    ),
    'maxWidth' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxWidth'),
        'message' => 'Your image width is too large; maximum width %s.'
    ),
    'maxHeight' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxHeight'),
        'message' => 'Your image height is too large; maximum height %s.'
    ),
    'filesize' => array(
        'rule' => array('filesize'),
        'message' => 'O ficheiro de ve ter um tamanho inferior a 2MB.'
    ),
    'extension' => array(
        'rule' => array('extension'),
        'message' => 'O ficheiro de ter um formato %s.'
    ),
    'required' => array(
        'rule' => array('required'),
        'message' => 'Seleccione uma fotografia por favor.',
        'on' => 'create',
        'allowEmpty' => true
    )
);

/**
 * Generated list of validation rules.
 *
 * @access protected
 * @var array
 */
protected $_validations = array();

/**
 * Setup the validation and model settings.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $config
 * @return void
 */
public function setup(Model $model, $config = array()) {
    if (!empty($config)) {
        foreach ($config as $field => $options) {
            $this->_settings[$model->alias][$field] = $options + array('required' => true);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Validates an image filesize. Default max size is 5 MB.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param int $size
 * @return boolean
 */
public function filesize(Model $model, $data, $size = 5242880) {
    if (empty($size) || !is_numeric($size)) {
        $size = 5242880;
    }

    foreach ($data as $fieldName => $field) {
        if ($this->_allowEmpty($model, $fieldName, $field)) {
            return true;

        } else if (empty($field['tmp_name'])) {
            return false;
        }

        return ($field['size'] <= $size);
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Checks that the image height is exact.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param int $size
 * @return boolean
 */
public function height(Model $model, $data, $size = 100) {
    return $this->_validateImage($model, $data, 'height', $size);
}

/**
 * Checks that the image width is exact.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param int $size
 * @return boolean
 */
public function width(Model $model, $data, $size = 100) {
    return $this->_validateImage($model, $data, 'width', $size);
}

/**
 * Checks the maximum image height.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param int $size
 * @return boolean
 */
public function maxHeight(Model $model, $data, $size = 100) {
    return $this->_validateImage($model, $data, 'maxHeight', $size);
}

/**
 * Checks the maximum image width.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param int $size
 * @return boolean
 */
public function maxWidth(Model $model, $data, $size = 100) {
    return $this->_validateImage($model, $data, 'maxWidth', $size);
}

/**
 * Checks the minimum image height.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param int $size
 * @return boolean
 */
public function minHeight(Model $model, $data, $size = 100) {
    return $this->_validateImage($model, $data, 'minHeight', $size);
}

/**
 * Checks the minimum image width.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param int $size
 * @return boolean
 */
public function minWidth(Model $model, $data, $size = 100) {
    return $this->_validateImage($model, $data, 'minWidth', $size);
}

/**
 * Validates the ext and mimetype.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param array $allowed
 * @return boolean
 */
public function extension(Model $model, $data, array $allowed = array()) {
    foreach ($data as $fieldName => $field) {
        if ($this->_allowEmpty($model, $fieldName, $field)) {
            return true;

        } else if (empty($field['tmp_name'])) {
            return false;

        } else {
            $ext = Uploader::ext($field['name']);
        }

        return (Uploader::checkMimeType($ext, $field['type']) && (empty($allowed) || in_array($ext, $allowed)));
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Makes sure a file field is required and not optional.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param boolean $required
 * @return boolean
 */
public function required(Model $model, $data, $required = true) {
    foreach ($data as $fieldName => $field) {
        if ($required && (!is_array($field) || empty($field['tmp_name']))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Build the validation rules and validate.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param Model $model
 * @return mixed
 */
public function beforeValidate(Model $model) {
    if (!empty($this->_settings[$model->alias])) {
        foreach ($this->_settings[$model->alias] as $field => $rules) {
            $validations = array();

            foreach ($rules as $rule => $setting) {
                $set = $this->_defaults[$rule];

                // Parse out values
                if (!isset($setting['value'])) {
                    $setting = array('value' => $setting);
                }

                switch ($rule) {
                    case 'required':    $arg = (bool) $setting['value']; break;
                    case 'extension':   $arg = (array) $setting['value']; break;
                    default:            $arg = (int) $setting['value']; break;
                }

                if (!isset($setting['rule'])) {
                    $setting['rule'] = array($rule, $arg);
                }

                if (isset($setting['error'])) {
                    $setting['message'] = $setting['error'];
                    unset($setting['error']);
                }

                unset($setting['value']);

                // Merge settings
                $set = array_merge($set, $setting);

                // Apply validations
                if (is_array($arg)) {
                    $arg = implode(', ', $arg);
                }

                $set['message'] = __d('uploader', $set['message'], $arg);

                $validations[$rule] = $set;
            }

            if (!empty($validations)) {
                if (!empty($model->validate[$field])) {
                    $validations = $validations + $model->validate[$field];
                }

                $this->_validations[$field] = $validations;
                $model->validate[$field] = $validations;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Allow empty file uploads to circumvent file validations.
 *
 * @access protected
 * @param Model $model
 * @param string $fieldName
 * @param array $field
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _allowEmpty(Model $model, $fieldName, $field) {
    if (isset($this->_validations[$fieldName]['required'])) {
        $rule = $this->_validations[$fieldName]['required'];
        $required = isset($rule['rule'][1]) ? $rule['rule'][1] : true;

        if (empty($field['tmp_name'])) {
            if ($rule['allowEmpty']) {
                return true;

            } else if ($required) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Validates multiple combinations of height and width for an image.
 *
 * @access protected
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $data
 * @param string $type
 * @param int $size
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _validateImage(Model $model, $data, $type, $size = 100) {
    foreach ($data as $fieldName => $field) {
        if ($this->_allowEmpty($model, $fieldName, $field)) {
            return true;

        } else if (empty($field['tmp_name'])) {
            return false;
        }

        $file = getimagesize($field['tmp_name']);

        if (!$file) {
            return false;
        }

        $width = $file[0];
        $height = $file[1];

        switch ($type) {
            case 'width':       return ($width == $size); break;
            case 'height':      return ($height == $size); break;
            case 'maxWidth':    return ($width <= $size); break;
            case 'maxHeight':   return ($height <= $size); break;
            case 'minWidth':    return ($width >= $size); break;
            case 'minHeight':   return ($height >= $size); break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: poderia postar seu arquivo `app/Plugin/Uploader/Model/Behavior/FileValidationBehavior.php`, assim fica mais fácil de achar o erro.

Comment: @ErlonCharles editei a minha pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa do `unset()` na linha 283 do arquivo `app/Plugin/Uploader/Model/Behavior/FileValidationBehavior.php`, a presença do *offset* *'error'* não vai interferir no funcionamento.
O erro é causado por você estar tentando remover um *offset* em uma variável em um `foreach()`.

O motivo para que esse erro tenha acontecido apenas quando você fez o upload do projeto é a diferença entre as versões do php da sua máquina e do seu ambiente de homologação(ou produção não sei)

Answer (score 0):

Penso ter encontrado a solução num  [problema](https://github.com/milesj/uploader/issues/136) semelhante.